# Having problem in coin tossing problem

Tags: probability

I was going through this question on a site. It stated as below,

> One more problem that is tying me up..I think because it is so much
>   simpler than what I have been working on. Any help would be great =)
>
> What is the probability of getting exactly $6$ heads and $3$ tails in $9$
>   coin tosses of an unbiased coin?

Now I were to solve the problem, I would have made a table of all the **heads** and **tails**. But this problem size is **very big** ($2^9$ is *large*). Is there any other possible way to solve the problem?

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: The number of heads or tails in a coin toss is a [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)  random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since coin is unbiased all possible 9-tuples have equal probability. Now applying the school definition of probability, $p = \frac{N_f}{N_t}$, i.e. the fraction of the number favorable outcomes over the number of total outcomes.

The total number of outcomes is $2^9$ as you noted. The number of favorable outcomes is given by the number of ways to choose $6$ slots for the head out of 9. This is $\binom{9}{6} = 84$.

Thus the probability

$$
   p = \frac{\binom{9}{6}}{2^9} = \frac{84}{2^9} \sim  0.164
$$

Comment: How did you calculated that those 9 tuples?

Comment: 9-tuple is a name for collection of 9 outcomes, what I was saying is that all outcomes of 9 tossings are equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you record the outcome of each coin toss; you will get strings like

> - `T T T T T T F F F`
> - `T F T F F T F T T`
> - `F F F F F F F F F`

Now what is the probability of each string? HINT Remember that each string is equally likely since the coin is unbiased.

Now you count a subset of these strings (or outcomes). Exactly which ones? Those strings that have exactly 6 heads and remaining tails. Do you know how to count the number of such strings?